# The package javax.xml.namespace is accessible from more than one module

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

My environment:

- Java 11
- Spring Boot
- Gradle

Not sure how to fix this error:

```
The package javax.xml.namespace is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

As many other questions and answers related this topic suggests, the error is related to a duplicity with java.xml import. By default, on Java 11, java.xml is part of the JDK libraries, and is added in the modulepath.

Check the dependencies of your graddle, at least one of then is also adding a transitive dependence to java.xml but in the classpath (unnamed module),thus it is present twice.

Locate the dependency that is adding it, and try adding something similar to this on you gradle (in my case the duplicity was due to Apache Tika library):

```
compile ('org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:1.22') {
    exclude (group: 'xml-apis')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
My envt was Java, Eclipse IDE, Java 8.
The fix for me was:
Properties -> Java Build Path -> Move my JRE System Library from the Modules to the Classpath.

Wonder if it has something to do with this package being both in my system library rt.jar file and in my project lib/jaxb-api.jar file and the way module imports work in Eclipse.